# Why does PHP json_encode flatten array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this PHP array (`$savedRequestDates`) of dates:

```
Array ( [0] => 2018-03-29 10:56:31 [1] => 2018-03-29 10:58:09 [2] => 2018-04-12 11:28:41 [3] => 2018-04-12 13:07:25 [4] => 2018-05-09 13:08:07 )
```

At the bottom of the same .php page I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sessions = new Array('<?php echo json_encode($savedRequestDates); ?>');
console.log(sessions[0]);
</script>
```

The `console.log(sessions[0]);` returns:

```
["2018-03-29 10:56:31","2018-03-29 10:58:09","2018-04-12 11:28:41","2018-04-12 13:07:25","2018-05-09 13:08:07"]
```

Why is the JavaScript array flattening at the 0 index? If I try `console.log(sessions);` it returns an array with one variable, not 5, as the php array clearly shows.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you're wrapping the array from PHP which another array (`new Array`). Just remove the `new Array` part and it will work fine.

```
var sessions = <?php echo json_encode($savedRequestDates); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the call to `json_encode`will create a full JSON object and not just the content of the array. You are enclosing the entire output of the PHP generated array as index 0 inside the `new Array`.

So removing the `new Array` will generate what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sessions = <?php echo json_encode($savedRequestDates); ?>;
console.log(sessions);
</script>
```

And you should see the entire array.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the help.